# ORA-12170 when connecting from Windows VM to Linux VM

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle19c

I have two local VM:

- VM#1 hostname LINUXVM, running on Linux 8 with Oracle 19c SE2 Database.
- VM#2 hostname WINDOWSVM, running on Windows 10 with Oracle 32 Bit Instant Client installed.

The DB is up and running and I can connect via sqlplus in VM#1 to my database using

```
sqlplus sys/[PWD]@[INSTANCE] as sysdba
```

**However, if I try to do the same from VM#2 I get an ORA-12170 (TNS:Connect timeout occured).**

Pinging the hostname works from both machines (I added the DB's IP address to both hosts files). VM#1 has been assigned a static IP address (192.168.1.177)

The listener is configured as follows:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.177)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

The tnsnames.ora is configured for both VMs as follows:

```
[INSTANCE] =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.177)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = [INSTANCE])
    )
  )
```

On VM#1's firewall, I allowed incoming TCP traffic on port 1521:
[image: Firewall rule]

UPDATE:
I applied Wireshark and seems that VM#1 (IP .177) cannot send back to VM#2 (IP .230).
As soon as I switch off the Firewall on VM#1 everything works fine. When I  switch it on, I get the error even though my firewall on VM#1 accepts all incoming and outgoing traffic from/to IP .230

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing the tnsnames.ora entry as like below instead of using SERVICE_NAME.

[INSTANCE] =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.177))(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SID = [INSTANCE])
)

Also, make sure that the client installed on the VM#2 is compatible with "Oracle 19c SE2 Database"

Comment: I tried it as you suggested but it didn't work

Comment: Best avoid SIDs - they were obsoleted a decade, or more, ago.  Use service names.

Comment: Ok but it doesn't work either :)

Comment: @MrGrEEN - and exactly why do you think using SID instead of SERVICE_NAME would address a network connection timeout?